# Adding multiple number fields together based on yes/no answers in Access

Tags: ms-access

It's been years since I've worked with Access/VBA so most of what I learned has been forgotten.  That said, I'm trying to create a table with multiple numeric fields that I would like to add together on a form based on whether or not someone selected yes/no.

I have the following type of setup

```
Field_A   (Number)
Field_A_Check   (yes/no)
Field_B   (Number)
Field_B_Check  (yes/no)
Field_C   (Number)
Field_C_Check   (yes/no)
```

If someone clicks `yes` next to `Field_A` and `Field_C`, I want to calculate the total in `Field_A` and `Field_C` together and capture that total on a form text box.  If someone else clicks `yes` next to `Field_B` only, I want to calculate just that number for that field only.

I've done a nested `iif` statement on the form, but it became so convoluted, I'd get lost.  It also doesn't seem like the best way to tackle this either.  Any additional help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `true` & `false` boolean field values are represented by the integers `-1` & `0` respectively, you can use the following single expression to calculate the total:

```
=-Field_A*Field_A_Check-Field_B*Field_B_Check-Field_C*Field_C_Check
```

Here, if any of the `_Check` fields are unchecked (`false`), the field value will be zero thus omitting the corresponding value from the sum.